# Enviar datos de un formulario a otro según quien lo invoque C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Quiero pasar datos de un formulario a otro dependiendo de quien invoque el formulario de búsqueda, por ejemplo:

Existen 2 formularios:

- frmRecursosMantenimiento
- frmReservaLab

y adicionalmente tengo un formulario de búsqueda llamado `frmRecursoBusqueda`. En mis formularios principales tengo un TextBox en el cual se recibe el código de un recurso el cual se encuentra en un Datagrid del formulario de búsqueda. Lo que necesito es enviar el dato de código pero según quien llame al formulario.

Por ejemplo: Si yo abro el formulario de búsqueda desde `frmRecursosMantenimiento`, el codigo lo puedo enviar a ese formulario y en caso de que abra `frmReservaLab` de igual forma lo pueda enviar a ese formulario.

Answer (score 1):

Digamos que en el main de la clase, se puede agregar otro constructor que indique desde qué formulario viene y se asigna a una variable privada interna de la clase (formulario);por ejemplo:

```
frmRecursoBusqueda(){
...;
}
```

y el otro constructor sería:

```
private string frmDe = new string.Empty;

fromRecursoBusqueda(string frmDesde){
frmDe = frmDesde;
...;
}
```

En el momento de llamar al formulario de Búsqueda, se debería llamar desde cualquiera así:

```
Form frmBusq = new frmBusqueda("frmReservaLab");
```

y Listo, ya tienes de dónde viene y puedes empezar a jugar con tu búsqueda.

Ahora bien, si deseas enviar otro dato adicional al nombre o diferente, simplemente agregas el dato que requieras en otro constructor así:

```
private string frmDe = new string.Empty;
private strng txtDato = new string.Empty;

fromRecursoBusqueda(string frmDesde, string txtDatoBuscar){
frmDe = frmDesde;
txtDato = txtDatoBuscar;
...;
}
```

Y símplemente lo llamas desde cualquiera de las dos clases así:

```
Form frmBusq = new frmBusqueda("frmReservaLab", TextBoxObjeto.Text);
```

Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 1):

Probablemente lo que necesites es un callback para que muevas información entre formularios de forma dinámica.

```
var recursoBusqueda = new frmRecursoBusqueda(x=>{
    txtCodigo.Text = x; //en caso de que quieras regresar un string
});
//en la clase de tu frmRecursoBusqueda 
private Action<string> _callback;
public frmRecursoBusqueda(Action<string> callback)
{
    _callback=callback;
}
//al ejecutar un evento clic de un botón
private void btAceptar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   _callback(/*el dato en string que quieras regresar*/);
   Close();
}
```

Considera que además de regresar string puedes regresar cualquier tipo de dato, si necesitas varios datos te recomendaría meterlos en una clase con sus respectivas propiedades para que te sea más claro conforme vaya creciendo el proyecto.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

En el `frmRecursoBusqueda` podrías tener una property pública y desde `frmRecursosMantenimiento` o `frmReservaLab` setear dicha propiedad con el valor esperado. Tendrías que subir el llamado al formulario de búsqueda para poder darte una mejor solución.